# Run-Time Error 424 In VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a script that searches a workbook, then prints the results on a worksheet. It all seems to work really well, but a problem that I am having is that whenever I open up the file, I get a run-time error 424. 
The debugger stops under Sub UpdateSearchBox() and it is line 4 or "If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then"

This is the code.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End Sub


Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    UpdateSearchBox
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Select Case TextBox1.Value
        Case "F"
            TextBox1.Value = "G"
        Case "E"
            TextBox1.Value = "F"
        Case "D"
            TextBox1.Value = "E"
        Case "C"
            TextBox1.Value = "D"
        Case "B"
            TextBox1.Value = "C"
        Case "A"
            TextBox1.Value = "B"
        Case "G"
            TextBox1.Value = "A"
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    FindOne
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    UpdateSearchBox
End Sub

Sub UpdateSearchBox()
    Dim PageName As String, searchColumn As String, ListFiller As String
    Dim lastRow As Long

    If TextBox1.Value <> "" Then
        PageName = TextBox1.Value
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case ComboBox2.Value
        Case "EQUIPMENT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "A"
        Case "EQUIPMENT NAME"
            searchColumn = "C"
        Case "DUPONT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "F"
        Case "SAP NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "G"
        Case "SSI NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "H"
        Case "PART NAME"
            searchColumn = "I"
        Case ""
            MsgBox "Please select a value for what you are searching by."
    End Select

    lastRow = Sheets(PageName).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

        If lastRow <> 0 And PageName <> "" And searchColumn <> "" Then
        ListFiller = PageName & "!" & searchColumn & "2" & ":" & searchColumn & lastRow
        ComboBox1.ListFillRange = ListFiller
    End If
End Sub
Sub FindOne()

    Range("B19:J1500") = ""

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim k As Integer, EndPasteLoopa As Integer
    Dim myText As String, searchColumn As String
    Dim totalValues As Long
    Dim nextCell As Range

    k = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    myText = ComboBox1.Value
    Set nextCell = Range("B20")
    If myText = "" Then
        MsgBox "No Address Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Select Case ComboBox2.Value
        Case "EQUIPMENT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "A"
        Case "EQUIPMENT NAME"
            searchColumn = "C"
        Case "DUPONT NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "F"
        Case "SAP NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "G"
        Case "SSI NUMBER"
            searchColumn = "H"
        Case "PART NAME"
            searchColumn = "I"
        Case ""
            MsgBox "Please select a value for what you are searching by."
    End Select

    For i = 2 To k
        totalValues = Sheets(i).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim AddressArray(totalValues) As String

        For j = 0 To totalValues
            AddressArray(j) = Sheets(i).Range(searchColumn & j + 1).Value
        Next j

        For j = 0 To totalValues
            If (myText = AddressArray(j)) Then
                EndPasteLoop = 1
                If (Sheets(i).Range(searchColumn & j + 2).Value = "") Then EndPasteLoop = Sheets(i).Range(searchColumn & j + 1).End(xlDown).Row - j - 1
                For r = 1 To EndPasteLoop
                    Range(nextCell, nextCell.Offset(0, 8)).Value = Sheets(i).Range("A" & j + r, "I" & j + r).Value
                    Set nextCell = nextCell.Offset(1, 0)
                Next r
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the code of `Sub UpdateSearchBox()` inside the `User_form` code module ? or another module ? If it's in another module, you need to add the user_form as a referrence. For instance, `PageName = TextBox1.Value` should be `PageName = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value`

Comment: i think that fixed it! Thank you!